# How to join table using linking table without having common column

Tags: database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, relationship

How could we join these student_info and class_info tables there is no common column but both foreign keys are store in class_student table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust to fit your WHERE clause, specific database, and JOIN needs.

For a student's classes:

```
SELECT *
FROM student_info JOIN class_student ON student_info.student_id = class_student.student_id
                  JOIN class_info    ON class_student.class_id  = class_info.class_id
WHERE student_info.student_id = ...
```

For a class's students:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM class_info JOIN class_student ON class_info.class_id      = class_student.class_id
                 JOIN student_info  ON class_student.student_id = student_info.student_id
 WHERE class_info.class_id = ...
```